# Permanent Enchanted Items in Dresden Files

Tags: dresden-files

Alright, I got into an argument with one of my players about his armor. He has a character with 5 lore and his Thaumaturgy bonus is to strength. He says that somewhere in the book Your Story he found that he could half his rating (6) and make his coat into armor 3. That we have found, but then he says that he can make it permanent by halving the total again, for an armor 1 that is always on. We cannot find that part, and for the time being I have allowed it, but I was wondering if someone could point me to the page that this is found on, or tell me if this is just bull.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was apparently a change in the enchanted items rules between the printing of the books and the early access PDFs that were sent out.  The original always-on rule appears in the early access PDF, but not in the printed Your Story rulebook for Dresden Files RPG.

So all of the below from my original answer may be completely ignored if you so choose.

**From those PDFs**, on page 279 of Your Story -

> The uses-per-session limitation may be removed by halving the base strength, rounded
>   down; so if you have Good (+3) Lore, you could create a one-use-per-session item with an effect strength of Good (+3), or an always-on item with an effect strength of Average (+1).

Combining this with the block effect used as armor rule on page 252 that you reference, that would make it a 6 point block spell, halved to be converted to an Armor:3 usable spell effect, and halved again to make an Armor:1 always-on.

This is basically a copy of Harry Dresden's leather coat, which is actually an example listed on page 303.

> **Harry’s Duster**
>   Susan Rodriguez gave Harry his leather duster.
>   He stitched arcane patterns into the tough material,
>   weaving defensive spells into the coat. It
>   doesn’t offer much armor, but it is very light.
>   *Spell provided*: At the time he crafts this (after
>   his first few casefiles), Harry’s Lore is effectively
>   Great (+4), halved to make it alwayson,
>   for 2 shifts of effect, halved again to act as
>   Armor:1. Uses one enchanted item slot.

**In the printed official rulebook**, there are several ways to increase the number of uses per session for any individual item - decreasing it's strength by one provides one additional use, using another enchanted item slot provides two additional uses, and the effect can always be triggered again by taking one point of mental stress.  However, the always-on effect rule has been removed.

The section does note that defensive items simply consume a use at time of defense rather than requiring an action to activate, so your player may well be able to work with that once he figures out how to invest in the item.

As well, the Duster example has been changed to an Armor:2 usable effect example, with additional uses (3/session) provided by using an additional item slot.

Comment: I literally have both the pdf and physical books open to that page and cannot find the part you are referencing.

Comment: @Discadae - Just in case I had a wonky PDF I just checked my physical copy too.  It's in there; uses-per-session is under Enchanted Items, a few paragraphs in.  The Duster example is the very first thing under Example Enchanted Items on it's page.  Are you looking at Our World or Your Story?

Comment: I am looking at your story both book and pdf, and have looked at other pdfs aand they are all saying the same thing, which is ""You may increase the number of uses per
session by one by reducing the base strength
of the item by one. So if you have Good (+3)
Lore, you could create an enchanted item with
an effect strength of Good (+3) that you can
use once per session, or an item with an effect
strength of Average (+1) that you can use three
times per session. When doing this, the base
strength of the item may not go below 1."" but then I am also looking on forums for your quote and it exists

Comment: I trust my player, but right now I am not able to find this quote despite almost an hour of searching. ARGHHHHHHH

Comment: @Discadae - *scratches head*  Was there a second edition or an altered printing that I never heard about?  Huh.  I'll dig a bit deeper.  But I swear it's in front of me.  Maybe that'll do for you for now.

Comment: I must have the same PDF as @Discadae, but the "half power for always on" seems like a reasonable rule of thumb for this sort of thing regardless. It's not gonna break anything. (Also, Harry's coat on 303 is a 3/use/session item for me.)

Comment: the next session isn't for 2 weeks so I have plenty of time to go crazy over this.

Comment: Allright, I'm the nuts one.  Re-read the physical copy and it is different from my PDF.  Just looked similar enough to fool me on a skim.

Comment: Dont feel bad, there are apparently 2 copies of pdfs out and one says what you have. My player must have read it in his pdf. BTW these people have the same issue http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=662.160 middle of the page

Comment: There are other differences you might need to keep an eye out for too. In the older version several Fists stunts require you to first take the *Martial Arts* stunt.